# Have special comments that change a Babel plugin's behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, comments, babeljs

I am trying to write a Babel transformer plugin for my project. However, it's functionality should be controlled per file, so I would like to be able to add

```
/**
 * @lazyLoad off
 */
```

At the beginning of the file and disable my plugin. I saw that Babel creates a `comments` key in the AST that contains the comments in a file and could probably help me, but I am not familiar with the Babel API so I am not sure how to get the comments, efficiently traverse them and check for something that I'm interested in.

Could you help me on that, please?